# Why isn't the data is not completely get replaced on 'replaceWith' Function in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

am trying to replace the current data which is displayed through an ajax  method with the result of another function,
In the First method i have used "append" method,and to update with new result I have tried replaceWith function,But the thing is ,Which only displays a single value.

> Displaying using append method:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function test() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WomenData",
                    method: "GET",
                    //data: { minimum_range: minimum_range, maximum_range: maximum_range },
                    success: function (vlist) {
                        for (var i in vlist) {

                        $('#card-group').append($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid='+vlist[i].mid+',mrate='+vlist[i].mrate+'" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));
                                          }
                }
            });

        }
        window.onload = test();
    });
```

> Updating using replaceWith method

```
function load_product(minimum_range, maximum_range) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Women",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { minimum_range: minimum_range, maximum_range: maximum_range },
                    success: function (vlist) {
                        for (var i in vlist) 
                        {
                            $('#card-group').replaceWith($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid=' + vlist[i].mid + ',mrate=' + vlist[i].mrate + '" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));

                        }

                    }
```

[image: Output of Replacewith function]

[image: Console Log]

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `append` doesn't care about the content `div` already have and keep pushing the content in the div.
While the `replaceWith` method removes the old content of the div everytime and then add the new content resulting the last index of the array to be the content of your div `$('#card-group')`

Here's the right solution. Just empty the div outside the loop then append to it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function test() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WomenData",
                method: "GET",
                //data: { minimum_range: minimum_range, maximum_range: maximum_range },
                success: function (vlist) {
                $('#card-group').empty();

                    for (var i in vlist) {

                    $('#card-group').append($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid='+vlist[i].mid+',mrate='+vlist[i].mrate+'" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));
                                      }
            }
        });

    }
    window.onload = test();
});
```

Comment: I tried sir. But the result is same. Only one raw is displayed

Comment: sir still the same problem exist

Comment: How many items are there in your `vlist` ? Check that out please

Comment: i put an alert box to check the number of values coming into the list,and the values are coming perfectly,The problem is with displaying i think

Comment: Can you show the `console.log` of the data? Screenshot preferably

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199511/discussion-between-codeseeker-and-muhammad-osama).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .html() method in jQuery to replace the whole thing?

syntax:

```
$(selector).html(content)
```

example:

```
$('#myDiv').html('<div><p>jQuery</p></div>');
```

dynamic with template literals:

```
$('#myDiv').html(`<div><p>&{myVariable}</p></div>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all,What i had tried is  almost same as the First Answer,But instead of emptying parent div in first load,I put it in Json result code block,and also changed 'replaceWith' with 'append'

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "Women",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { minimum_range:ui.values[0], maximum_range:ui.values[1] },
                    success: function (vlist) {
                        $('#card-group').empty();
                        for (var i in vlist) {

                            $('#card-group').append($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid=' + vlist[i].mid + ',mrate=' + vlist[i].mrate + '" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));


                        }


                    }
                });
```